# Uninstall programs with Powershell silently

Tags: powershell

There are two programs which I need to Uninstall silently through powershell, I tried lots of scenario still nothing is working.
Particularly I need to uninstall these two programs "*Microsoft ASP.NET Core 3.1.16 Shared Framework (x64)*" & "*Microsoft ASP.NET Core 3.1.16 Shared Framework (x86)*"

I am trying these commands to uninstall but it's giving other option:

```
    PS C:\Windows\system32> $MyApp = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq "Microsoft ASP.NET Core 3.1.16 Shared Framework (x64)"}
    $MyApp.Uninstall()
    
    
    __GENUS          : 2
    __CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
    __SUPERCLASS     : 
    __DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
    __RELPATH        : 
    __PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
    __DERIVATION     : {}
    __SERVER         : 
    __NAMESPACE      : 
    __PATH           : 
    ReturnValue      : 0
    PSComputerName   :
```

Return value is 0 still it's not uninstalling anything.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I do not know if this is helpful but maybe this link is what you are looking for [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/core/additional-tools/uninstall-tool?tabs=windows)

Comment: @Malte I can't install  .NET Uninstall Tool as it's a restricted server

Comment: @Manish Is the product still registered after a reboot?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen It's a ASG server, we can't actually reboot the server. but for testing I can check that.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes after reboot the product is still there

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following PowerShell code to get the `UninstallString` for the products from the registry:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall", "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" | Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -match ".NET" } | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, UninstallString
```

```
DisplayName                                          UninstallString
-----------                                          ---------------
Microsoft ASP.NET Core 3.0.3 Shared Framework (x64)  MsiExec.exe /X{04DEAACD-DD28-3F35-980F-9B3123640CA7}
```

Then copy the appropriate `MsiExec /X{...}` commands from the output and paste them into an elevated PowerShell or cmd prompt, and add `/quiet` to the end to make them run silently.

[msiexec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msiexec)